# How to use retryWhen only 3 times then give up

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I want to filter when specific exception occurs during execution of some of the upper chain function and try to retry the whole process only 3 times then if it still failes then give up. I came to something like this:

```
   val disposable = someFunction(someParameter, delay, subject)
    .flatMapCompletable { (parameter1, parameter2) ->
      anotherFunction(parameter1, parameter2, subject)
    }
    .retryWhen { throwable ->
      throwable.filter {
        it.cause?.cause is ExampleException1
            || it.cause?.cause is ExampleException2
            || it.cause is ExampleException3
      }
    }
    .andThen(someStuff())
    .subscribe({
      Timber.d("Finished!")
    }, {
      Timber.d("Failed!")
    })
```

How to do it properly?

Answer (score 4):

You may use `zipWith` with a `range` to achieve this.

```
.retryWhen { errors -> errors.zipWith(Observable.range(1, 3), { _, i -> i }) }
```

The `retryWhen` operator gives you the stream of all the errors from your source publisher. Here you zip these with numbers 1, 2, 3. Therefore the resulting stream will emit 3 `next` followed by the `complete`. Contrary to what you may think this resubscribes only twice, as the `complete` emitted immediately after the third `next` causes the whole stream to complete.

You may extend this further, by retrying only for some errors, while immediately failing for others. For example, if you want to retry only for `IOException`, you may extend the above solution to:

```
.retryWhen { errors -> errors
  .zipWith(Observable.range(1, 3), { error, _ -> error })
  .map { error -> when (error) {
    is IOException -> error
    else -> throw error
  }}
}
```

Since `map` cannot throw a checked exception in Java, Java users may use `flatMap` for the same purpose.

Comment: do you know how this would be in java? :D

Comment: Instead of zipWith, why not just take(3)?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to do can be achieved with `retry` exclusively:

```
val observable = Observable.defer {
    System.out.println("someMethod called") 
    val result1 = 2 // some value from someMethod()
    Observable.just(result1)
}

observable.flatMap { result ->
    // another method is called here but let's omit it for the sake of simplicity and throw some exception
    System.out.println("someMethod2 called") 
    throw IllegalArgumentException("Exception someMethod2")
    Observable.just("Something that won't be executed anyways")
}.retry { times, throwable ->
            System.out.println("Attempt# " + times)
            // if this condition is true then the retry will occur
            times < 3 && throwable is IllegalArgumentException
        }.subscribe(
                { result -> System.out.println(result) },
                { throwable -> System.out.println(throwable.localizedMessage) })
```

**Output:**

> someMethod called
>
> someMethod2 called
>
> Attempt# 1
>
> someMethod called
>
> someMethod2 called
>
> Attempt# 2
>
> someMethod called
>
> someMethod2 called
>
> Attempt# 3
>
> Exception someMethod2

As `someMethod2` always throws an `Exception`, after 3 attempts `Exception someMethod2` is printed in `onError` of the observer.

Answer (score 0):

Code with exponential delay:

```
    YourSingle()
        .retryWhen { errors: Flowable<Throwable> ->
           errors.zipWith(
              Flowable.range(1, retryLimit + 1),
              BiFunction<Throwable, Int, Int> { error: Throwable, retryCount: Int ->
                if (error is RightTypeOfException && retryCount < retryLimit) {
                    retryCount
                } else {
                    throw error
                }
            }
        ).flatMap { retryCount ->
            //exponential 1, 2, 4
            val delay = 2.toDouble().pow(retryCount.toDouble()).toLong() / 2
            Flowable.timer(delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        }
    }
```